# How to get response from Google Translate API if translation is complete?

Tags: google-translate

I am using `Google Translation API` to translate text into multiple language by selecting Language from Google Translate's Drop down.

On selecting the language, text is being translated properly but I want to know a notification when it completes the translation so that I can trigger some event after its completion.

Is there any way to get response or message from `Google Translate API` which tell us that translation has been completed or any success `status/message`?